# Basic Hidden field in yii

Tags: php, yii, field, hidden, yii1.x

I'm trying to place data in hidden text in yii, but I don't know how. 
I need a similar code to a regular php syntax:

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="a"/>
```

It's supposed to be a field with static value of a. I just need it to go with my $_POST variables for error checking.

Is it possible to avoid modifying the models and controllers just to put the field in?I cant use gii cause I only have snippets of code with me.Sorry as well as I have little understanding of yii so I have no clue if what I'm saying about the last 2 sentences is correct.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.builder#specifying-form-elements  .this may help

Answer (score 58, accepted):

in views

hidden field **with** model and form:

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'name'); ?>
```

or **without** model

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('name' , 'value', array('id' => 'hiddenInput')); ?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Yii hidden input :

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model,'fieldName',array('value'=>'foo bar')); ?>
```

Answer (score 10):

In Yii2 this has changed too:

```
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'name') ;?>
```

References:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49225-activeform-how-do-you-call-label-input-and-errors-individually/

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/735

Answer (score 3):

if data from database and value or size field:

```
echo $form->hiddenField($experience,'job_title',array('size'=>'50','value'=>$experience_data['job_title'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yii 1

```
<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'name'); ?>
```

Yii2

```
<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'attribute', ['value' => 'Some Value']) ?>
```

Also, worth noting for Yii2, the array parameter works different to a normal form field.
E.G. A normal input would look more like this.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'attribute', ['inputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Some Placeholder', 'value' => 'Some Input Value']]) ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

for yii2 you can try this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'user_type',['inputOptions' => ['value' => '2']])->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

It worked for me

Comment: Works, but adds DIV.form-group and therefore takes place in the form visual...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively,

```
echo CHtml::activeHiddenField($model,"[$i]id", array("value" => $model->id));
```

This would set hidden field value as the id from model. The [$i] is useful for multiple record update.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do that...

**without model**

```
echo CHtml::hiddenField('name' , 'value', array('id' => 'name'));
```

**with model**

```
echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'name');
```